# Does the Singaporean constitution allow pardons to be revoked?

Tags: pardon, singapore

The Singaporean government allows for the power of pardon to the president but it doesn't include how the pardoning power is to be excercised and if the pardon can be revoked or not.

Comment: A pardon isn't really meaningful if it can be revoked by the next guy in office.

Comment: Do you have any reason at all to believe that a pardon can be revoked in Singapore?

Comment: @Questor can't pardons be revoked in USA or Canada

Comment: In the USA at least, only if the person who issued the pardon (IE the president) is impeached... And even then its not so cut and dry.

Comment: @Questor You are mistaken. In the U.S., pardons cannot be revoked, full stop, no exceptions. You could have a case where a document purporting to be a pardon turns out to be a forgery and that purported pardon would be invalid, and you can have a conditional pardon that only takes effect if something is done or at a future date, but a pardon cannot be revoked by anyone. An impeachment itself cannot  be pardoned in the first place, but that doesn't mean that a pardon can be revoked.

Comment: @ohwilleke President Ulysses S Grant Revoked 3 pardons made by President Johnson on his last day in office (last day of office of Johnson, first day of office for Grant)... (admittedly before they were delivered). The only literature on the subject "A Familiar Exposition of the Constitution" believes that in the case of impeachment of the pardoner the pardon can be revoked.

Comment: @Questor The vast weight of scholarly authority disagrees. An impeachment of a pardoner does not invalid it. The case of Grant involves pardons that weren't finished being issued under the concept of signed, sealed, and delivered . . . . i.e. a written instrument does not have legal effect, even if signed, until delivered to someone other than the issuer or their agent.